# What should we do about XBMC's new name?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

XBMC will be called kodi in newer versions, what should we do about it? People will still refer it to XBMC for several years to come, but some users will use the new name kodi.

I suggest that we make a new tag for kodi and update the current tag for xbmc that the new version uses kodi as name. And in the future xbmc should be a link to kodi, like trusty is for 14.04.

[Official statement of the new name.](http://xbmc.org/introducing-kodi-14/)

- [version 13.2 is the final release of XBMC](http://xbmc.org/xbmc-13-2-gotham-final-release/)
- [Kodi (version 14.0) is currently in Alpha 3](http://xbmc.org/kodi-14-0-helix-alpha-3/)

Answer (score 21):

What should we do? Nothing special.
Use [xbmc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xbmc) for XMBC and [kodi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kodi) for Kodi.

- People know what they're using (the branding has historically been quite strong)
- It'll be a while before XBMC stops existing. It'll be in the Trusty repos until 2019.
- The featureset of XBMC 12 and Kodi-latest will diversify as time rolls on. Keeping them separate helps us too.